# can predefined event be changed of dojo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dojo

can we change an predefined event of dojo.for example if in dojo we have an onclick event on a DateTextBox,when we click on it shows calander so now if I want that whenever I dblclick on it, it should show the calander not on single click, how can I do this please give some suggestion. I want it in dojo.

I have a inlineeditbox when i click it is editable now i want that when i double click on that it should be editable not on single click:

code is like:

```
<div editor="dijit.form.TextBox" dojoType="dijit.InlineEditBox"  style="cursor: pointer">editable text</div>
```

Comment: Please, read the FAQ. Give us some _code_!

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks please see the edited que.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't add much to your question. Are you using a Dojo plugin? If so, which one? Can you link us to a jsfiddle.net example so we can take a deeper look?

Comment: you can see it here :http://jsfiddle.net/mahipatidar13/FCaT6/12/ but it is not working I dont now why it is not working if any change need please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on the field. Chrome 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try (see http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/73tPD/):

```
<div id="myEditor" editor="dijit.form.TextBox" dojoType="dijit.InlineEditBox"  style="cursor: pointer"> Editable text. when i single click on it it is editable. now I want that it should be editable on dblclick</div>


dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
dojo.require("dijit.InlineEditBox");
dojo.ready(function(){
    var editor = dijit.byId("myEditor");
    editor._onClick = function(evt){
        console.debug("Do nothing");
    };
    editor.connect(editor.domNode, "dblclick", function(evt){
        editor.edit();
    });
});
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot for your answer. can I use it like var editor= dojo.query("div"); and then rest of the function ?

Comment: Not directly, but you can do something like var editorNode = dojo.query("div").pop(); var editor = dijit.byNode(editorNode); ...